# Why would it be illegal to inform about “abort”?

Tags: c, gnu, libc, code-documentation

The [GNU libc documentation of the `abort` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aborting-a-Program.html#Aborting-a-Program) contains the following notice:

> **Future Change Warning:** Proposed Federal censorship regulations may prohibit us from giving you information about the possibility of calling this function. We would be required to say that this is not an acceptable way of terminating a program.

Uh, what?

I found a seven-year-old [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/d4783/federal_censorship_regulations_may_restrict/) discussing this. It appears that the notice was put in by Richard Stallman in 1995 — so it’s been in there for a while. However, except for [a 1999 mailing list thread](https://sourceware.org/ml/glibc-linux/1999-q3/msg00013.html) claiming it’s a joke, I couldn’t find any further information.

So: is this just an Easter egg put in by rms? Or is it serious (though probably no longer relevant)? If so, what does/did it refer to?

The [Open Group POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/abort.html) of the same function doesn’t include anything similar, nor do any of the man pages I consulted.

Comment: (This is a serious question, by the way. Although I fear that it’s probably just a silly joke.)

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is about managing a business relationship, communicating between the question OP and a third party, and/or dealing with a legal issue. In other words, it's not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic]. You might be able to get help from the Customer Service for the company you are interfacing with. If you want an interpretation of legal requirements, it *might* be appropriate to ask on [law.se], but *read their on-topic page first*.

Comment: Yes, this is very likely a joke/expression of frustration regarding the legal/political situation at the time it was added to the code base, but it's fundamentally not a programming question. The question is about interpreting a comment that, while it's in a section of code, it's not actually about programming (i.e. it's not "[a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)").

Comment: @Makyen In my defence I thought it *was* potentially about programming, in particular about an actual legal consequence of this function in Texas (I thought it being a joke was vastly *more likely*, but by no means certain). That definitely makes it programming related and arguably on topic.

Comment: I can understand having that concern. However, even if there's a legal issue with the code, that's a legal issue, not a programming question. The question can be considered analogous to a licensing or copyright issue, which are also not on-topic. That the legal issue is brought up in a comment in a program doesn't change its fundamental nature of being a legal issue. You asking the question here is understandable and isn't a big deal, it's just doesn't fit within our narrow topicality. It looks like the question's been helpful to people and probably will remain so.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is a reference to abortion gag laws, which forbid even mentioning abortion.

[The Global Gag Rule](https://www.engenderhealth.org/media/info/definition-global-gag-rule/) was in place in the US in 1995-2009, was reinstated in 2017 and [revoked again in 2021](https://www.usaid.gov/global-health/legislative-policy-requirements):

> The “Global Gag Rule,” otherwise known as the Mexico City Policy, requires that any overseas organization receiving U.S. aid not have anything to do with abortion. Doctors, midwives, and nurses could not even mention the word abortion—much less provide abortion services with their own funds—even if it was legal in their country, or if a woman asks.

This is not directly related to software, but FSF has always been strongly opposed to all kinds of censorship legislation.

Comment: The "future change warning" was [already present](http://www.oldlinux.org/Linux.old/gnu/glibc/glibc-1.06.html#SEC399) in [glibc-manual-0.02.tar](http://www.oldlinux.org/Linux.old/gnu/glibc/glibc-manual-0.02.tar/glibc-manu.zip), April 1993, for glibc 1.06 ([released](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Glibc%20Timeline) on 1993-05-23). [GNU's Bulletin, vol. 1 no. 11, June, 1991](https://www.gnu.org/bulletins/bull11.html) [mentions](https://www.gnu.org/bulletins/bull11.html#SEC2) that [Sandra Loosemore](http://www.frogsonice.com/) started in 1991 so that might be the earliest date.

Comment: The warning has been removed in [7f0e1933f08d52b22b02fdcd075382506f7b2e9c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=7f0e1933f08d52b22b02fdcd075382506f7b2e9c), October 2019, while [a discussion was ongoing](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2019-October/107628.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would immediately assume it's a joke, yes.

My interpretation would be that it's some kind of reference to "abortion", i.e. stopping a pregnancy.